# What to do as a player when ranger animal companion dies

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, animal-companions

I recently found myself in a situation where my PHB Beastmaster's animal companion was killed. There were no suitable beasts in the vicinity.  As we were partway through a dungeon the party was unwilling to take a several day detour to replace the beast.

After a long rest the rest of the party was full health and ready to continue on but I had no new animal companion. My spells and equipment were optimized around the beast companion so without it over half my damage output was gone.

I ended up spending the rest of the dungeon casting cure wounds as there was little more I could do besides a single hand crossbow shot a turn.

Is there realistically anything I could have done or do Beastmaster rangers have to accept that if their beast companion dies they will be sitting on the sidelines until they can replace it?

DM flatly refused death saves on the animal companion stating it was not a PC.
RAW only; no UA or hand waving.

Comment: What was the level and class composition of your party at the time? There may have been options available to other characters that would have helped.

Comment: When you say your equipment was optimized around the animal companion, what do you mean? Do you have no other weapons than the hand crossbow? Beastmaster rangers are still fairly competent combatants in their own right, only missing out on a few combat features that other rangers get.

Comment: @MivaScott I've suggested that a couple of answers integrate this into their answers. Feel free to use this as an answer, but since this is an answer in the comments I am going to remove it.

Comment: Does your DM use PHB spells only or are you allowed spells from any of the supplements like xanathars?

Answer (score 15):

The Beastmaster Ranger's Ranger's Companion feature states:

> [...] If the beast dies, you can obtain another one by spending 8 hours magically bonding with another beast that isn't hostile to you, either the same type of beast as before or a different one...

This is the only way mentioned of acquiring a *new* companion, so unfortunately if that is not an option, you will not have a way of getting a new companion. That said, you do have a few options available:

### Finding a new companion

There is the [*locate animals or plants*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/locate-animals-or-plants) spell:

> Describe or name a specific kind of beast or plant. Concentrating on the voice of nature in your surroundings, you learn the direction and distance to the closest creature or plant of that kind within 5 miles, if any are present.

### Preventing the companion from dying:

Suggest to your GM that they allow your animal companions to make death saving throws. This would also give you more time to react once your companion begins to "die", potentially saving them. And it expressly mentioned in the following section:

> Most DMs have a monster die the instant it drops to 0 hit points, rather than having it fall unconscious and make death saving throws. Mighty villains and **special nonplayer characters** are common exceptions; **the DM might have them fall unconscious and follow the same rules as player characters.**

You could also use the [*death ward*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/death-ward) spell:

> You touch a creature and grant it a measure of protection from death.
>
> The first time the target would drop to 0 hit points as a result of taking damage, the target instead drops to 1 hit point, and the spell ends.
>
> If the spell is still in effect when the target is subjected to an effect that would kill it instantaneously without dealing damage, that effect is instead negated against the target, and the spell ends.

This spell lasts for eight hours, and so a Cleric/Paladin in your party may cast it for you, otherwise perhaps there is a spell-selling service in your world.

Comment: You may want to include something that MivaScott included in a deleted comment. The DM *can* allow animal companions to do death saves. This one seems under the impression that the rules say otherwise "Most DMs have a monster die the instant it drops to 0 hit points, rather than having it fall unconscious and make death saving throws. Mighty villains and **special nonplayer characters are common exceptions**; the DM might have them fall unconscious and follow the same rules as player characters."

Answer (score 11):

> Is there realistically anything I could have done or **do Beastmaster rangers have to accept that if their beast companion dies they will be sitting on the sidelines until they can replace it?**

#### RAW, it's the latter. Risking your resources against challenges is a big part of the game.

Beastmasters get some special advantages from their class features, as do any characters with class levels. Whether or not those features are balanced with one another across classes (by which I mean, is a Wizard as "good" as a Beastmaster) is a more nebulous question, but each class still specializes in certain ways and can be in trouble if something precludes their specialized capabilities.

For a Wizard, it's all about spells. If a Wizard PC chooses a not-very-useful set of spells before a dungeon dive that doesn't allow a long rest, they will be less effective than they might have been and have a harder time than they might have had. If the Wizard burns their spell slots early, they'll have a lot less utility later on. If they find themselves in an area filled with antimagic fields, or encountering lots of enemies with magic resistances, then they'll be much less valuable in their typical role.

For a Beastmaster Ranger, the specialization is in the beasts that they master. Your animal companion dying, while not *necessarily* preventable, is a situation akin to a pure Wizard being silenced, in an antimagic field, or in some other way having been prevented from using their spells. Especially if you're specialized around the animal companion, keeping that companion alive is as important for the Beastmaster as spell management and ability to cast spells are to Wizards. This dungeon may have been especially difficult for your character, since no suitable replacements were available.

In any of these cases the player's choices, and their circumstances and luck, impact which of their resources they hazard at a particular time. It may be necessary to risk an animal companion (or a PC companion!) to overcome an obstacle, and then you have that much less to bring to bear on future challenges. That sort of resource allocation is a very important element of the game, and not every risk pays off.

I say all of this not to put down the Beastmaster class specialization, but to highlight that the animal companion is a high-value resource which may not always be available. In the same way that a Wizard will use spell slots to advance in the dungeon and then not have them available afterwards, a Beastmaster's companion will help the party advance but might be "consumed" in doing so. It's easily fixed during downtime, but in an adventure featuring time pressure the inability to get a new companion might be similarly vexing as a Wizard's inability to take a long rest and restore spell slots-- whittling away at the party's resources is part of the adventure's challenge.

---

#### What can you do about the Beastmaster's vulnerability to losing their animal companion?

Having a list of options to resurrect the companion is valuable, though doing it mid-dungeon crawl may require assistance and investment from others in your party.

Being slightly less specialized around the companion may also be an option, depending on your tastes. Going all-in on the companion is an all-your-eggs-in-one-basket proposition, and the risk of that is that they all break at once and you're down to crossbow fire.

Most importantly, *talk to your DM*. The key angle is that your character is based around the animal companion, and presumably a good portion of your fun is related to that as well. Because the companion is a special class resource that can't be restored as easily as others (like by simply taking a long rest), your character may be particularly brittle relative to the other PCs. If that's impacting your fun, as seems to be the case, your DM may be willing to work with out to remove some of that brittleness.

I disagree with your DM's call that only PCs can make death saves. This is explicitly contrary to the published rules, which make no such restriction, but even if this were untrue (or your DM simply handles their table that way) a special accommodation could easily be made for the animal companion. Other options exist to make your character build a bit more resilient, such as *UA's* Revised Ranger allowing for a particular fallen companion to be restored over a long rest.

---

#### What can you do, generally, when your specialization is ineffective or unavailable?

There's no question that being deprived of your character's specializations takes some of the excitement out of the game-- those are what make your character shine! But even if your character is not able to do what they do best, they can still do a lot to help out:

- Healing is a *big deal*. Many combat situations expect the party to
  replenish HP, and even if it isn't your favorite thing there's no
  cause to feel bad about "just" healing.
- Helping. It's situational, but using the *Help* action to assist
  party members can also be valuable. Advantage is a meaningful
  benefit.
- Drawing fire/Engaging enemies. If your character has good AC, and/or
  can take a hit, engaging an enemy can be really useful. It
  potentially limits enemy mobility, and helps spread out enemy damage
  output rather than concentrating it on the rest of the party. I've
  had players do nothing but Dodge for rounds at a time, soaking up
  enemy attack actions without actually taking damage.
- Attacking. Damage adds up, and a single crossbow bolt can make the
  difference between a successful fight and a catastrophe.
- Grappling. If your character has the attributes for it, grappling an
  enemy can take them out of the fight for a time.

Answer (score 10):

### Pretend it is magical

This isn't RAW, but I have been in a similar situation and the DM worked a situation where the animal was 'blessed' (In our case by a powerful dragon) and bonded to the ranger in such a way that the spirit could be called in a very *find familiar*-ish manner.

This meant that the ranger was never more than an hour away from having a companion.

Note:
It is important to take into account the role play implications of this. A vulnerable companion can lead the ranger into making personal sacrifice for their animal, but an effectively indestructible companion would end up being played the other way round. This definitely isn't a solution for all tables.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is almost exactly the approach taken in the Beast Conclave archetype of the UA [Ranger, Revised](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/UA_RevisedRanger.pdf), which allows a slain animal companion to be resurrected by the expenditure of 25gp's worth of materials and an 8-hour ritual (original body parts not required).

Comment: You may want to include something that MivaScott included in a deleted comment. The DM *can* allow animal companions to do death saves. This one seems under the impression that the rules say otherwise "Most DMs have a monster die the instant it drops to 0 hit points, rather than having it fall unconscious and make death saving throws. Mighty villains and **special nonplayer characters are common exceptions**; the DM might have them fall unconscious and follow the same rules as player characters."

Answer (score 9):

### Resurrect it

In the immediate moment, an animal companion is a perfectly valid target for the spell [*revivify*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/revivify), which is available to clerics (and Celestial-patron warlocks) from 5th level and paladins from 9th. *Revivify* is so generally useful in an emergency that once the party has access to it, it would be quite remiss for nobody to have it prepared, and to try and leave at least one 3rd+ spell slot available to cast it. Fights are usually concluded inside of a minute so it should be a rare case that the caster cannot get to a fallen ally/companion in time to revive them.

This is a relatively expensive option as it costs 300gp of diamonds to *revivify* a creature. If you miss out on the minute window and have to go up to [*raise dead*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/raise-dead) instead, it requires a 500gp diamond and your companion will be quite nerfed until they've had a few rests to recover. In the event that the party is of the particularly stingy kind who might balk at spending that amount of money on resurrecting an animal, your ranger might want to consider getting ahold of the necessary jewellery with their own money so it can be used for material components should the situation arise.

Answer (score 8):

> Is there realistically anything I could have done or do Beastmaster rangers have to accept that if their beast companion dies they will be sitting on the sidelines until they can replace it?
>
> DM flatly refused death saves on the animal companion stating it was not a PC.

I'm afraid the answer is pretty simple.  Don't play a Beastmaster ranger when the DM's choice of rules will predictably make your companion regularly die.

Being reduced to 0 HP in a 5e fight is pretty typical against challenging foes, and your beast companion isn't ridiculously tough like a barbarian or moon druid.

So your beast companion is going to regularly be reduced to 0 HP if your fights are ever tough.  If you aren't playing in environments where you can easily get a new companion, and death saving throws aren't allowed, you will regularly be "useless" in the sense of "not have an animal companion".

And it is a matter of DM's choice of rules, not "playing by RAW" or whatever:

The 5e rules state that PCs get saving throws, monster's generally don't, and **Mighty villains and special nonplayer characters are common exceptions;** and get death saves.  A beast companion is about a special as a nonplayer character gets.

So, the DM is free to state "beast companions die at 0 HP", but that just means you should avoid playing Beastmaster Rangers in that DM's world if you want to tell the story of a competent adventurer.

Find a style of PC your DM supports as being competent, and play that.  I'd avoid being creative in your second choice of PC with that DM, as you don't want to run into having yet another PC be proven useless due to rules interpretation.  Instead, just pick a type of PC that other characters have already chosen to be acceptable to the DM.

Comment: I'll take "things that should have been mentioned in a Session Zero for 500" , Alex.

Answer (score 3):

Plenty of people have supplied mechanical solutions to your situation. I'm going to highlight the in-character roleplaying and out-of-character group issues this scenario brings up.

**In-Character:** As a ranger, your animal companion has just died. You have fought alongside it and it has fought alongside you. It is stronger because of you (mechanically-enforced via your proficiency bonus being granted to its AC, attack rolls, damage rolls, and saving throws & skills it's proficient in) and you are stronger because of it (it provides large chunks of the ranger's damage output).

**You have suffered loss and your fellow party members don't care enough to make a detour so you can mourn your animal companion for 8 hours as you find another companion to temper the wound? Leave them. They're a terrible party for a ranger to travel with because they don't respect the bond you have with your companion(s).** OOC: Consider rejoining the game with a different class or exiting your current character until they can come back with another beast companion.

**Out-of-character:** Your fellow players and/or GM are taking action that makes the game no longer fun for you because you're not able to enjoyably participate. Your animal companion dying is a valid risk inherent to the beast master archetype... but your players are telling you they're willing to carry-on game at the expense of your fun instead of spending 8 hours in-game to make it so you can effectively play your class.

**If the majority's fun comes at the cost of your own, it's time to assess the game table. Are these the people you want to spend your free-time with? Do you trust in the GM facilitating fun anymore after this?**

Comment: Welcome to RPG stack exchange! This seems like a solid first post! However, I don't really get your structuring. It looks like you want put IC and OOC side by side (so to speak) for different considerations, but with the mixed formatting it does not really seem to work out.

Answer (score 3):

You could now ask you GM whether you can use the alternative to the Beast Master ranger which appears in *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* (TCoE, p.61):
***"Primal Companion**, 3rd-level Beast Master feature, which replaces the Ranger's Companion freature."*

This makes the Beast Master much easier to manage in a situation such as the one you described, for a couple of reasons:

1. summoning
2. returning your beast to life

This alternative to the ranger sub-class, says *"You magically summon a primal beast, which draws strength from your bone with nature.* [...] *When you finish a long rest, you can summon a different primal beast. The new beast appears in an onoccupied space within 5 feet of you.*

The **Primal Companion** alternative also provides you with a way of returning the beast back to life: *"If the beast has died within the last hour, you can use your action to touch it and expend a spell slot of 1st level or higher. The beast returns to life after 1 minute with all its hit points restored."*

Not only that, there are *three* options to choose from for your companion, a beast of the land, of the sea or of the sky. Your ranger's companion will also evolve as your PC increases in ranger levels, proficiency bonus modifier and spell attack modifier.

- Ranger Levels increases: Hit Points
- PB increases: AC, damage
- Spell attack modifier increases: to Hit bonus (attack modifier)

I think this option of the rules would have made your experience of the campaign much more enjoyable; you wouldn't have to spend a section of it just shooting your crossbow and casting the odd *Cure Wounds* here and there.

Answer (score 2):

## Tell the rest of the party that you *need* to leave the dungeon to get a new animal companion, and do not compromise.

Just like a Wizard who has run out of spells, you need to retreat from the dungeon and take a long rest to regain the functionality of your class - and Ranger is already widely regarded as the weakest class in the game to begin with. If the rest of the party doesn't comply, just have your character turn around and leave without them. If the party doesn't follow along you or otherwise take a long rest so that you can regain the party, just tell them that the alternative is having your character kill himself so that you can roll up a new character, and thereby delay the game while you do that, or for you to get up and go home while your character is off by himself and the rest of the party ignores him.

This isn't the best option, or the first one you should try, but if they're not going to listen to reason, then the only option you have is to twist their arms. If they don't comply even, then, just get up, tell them that you hope they'll enjoy the rest of the night, and leave the game and go home. No DnD is better than bad DnD.

Comment: I fully encourage a player to find a way to enjoy the game, but I would hope they take into account how their behavior impacts the other player's ability to enjoy the game as well.  A player throwing a fit and threatening to kill off their PC can be disruptive to the entire table in a bad way, and also reinforces negative behavior if allowed.  I would much rather the player exercise the use of lore and RP to ensure they are having a fun.  A Ranger's bond with their companion is a big deal in lore and could be used to RP a less disruptive exit from the party to achieve the same goals.

Answer (score -1):

As your DM I would do one of the following:

**Case 1**: Your animal companion character was not the most important thing for your PC. It matters more that the role is filled and the bond goes beyond the physical animal occupying that role.

I don't let you roll death saves. Me and the party have a bit of fun at your expense seeing you stumble for a couple of in game days feeling useless and then I present you an opportunity to bond with a beast native to the environment you are in. A long rest is enough for that after the target is found. Maybe 2 if we are playing rp heavy sessions.

**Case 2**: Your animal companion was a friend. Integral to your backstory and a consistent ally.

I let you roll deaths save. We probably spent some time homebrewing it too so it can keep up with the party leveling up so I don't want it to die too. But If it perma dies we discuss if you are interested in multiclassing to change direction or if you are insistent on finding a new companion. Whatever your choice for the character's path forward it's gonna take time. Like multiple sessions kind of time and if the party is not willing to take part on that journey with you. Your PC leaves. You join with a new character sheet. The ranger might rejoin if you want after some months of ingame time pass. Or maybe even seek revenge from the party that abandoned him if you too abandon him to be property of the game world.

**Most Important**
Whatever the case or choice we have resolve as a group why noone cared enough for the ranger to help him out. My guess for what I have seen more often be the issue here. Your PCs don't talk to one another. RP some mundane stuff, pranks, namecalling, infight banter. Whatever you enjoy as a group of friends playing a game. I feel that groups that invest in PC relations would leave almost most quests to resolve a personal PC issue.